# How to apply bootstrap css to Primefaces custom compoents

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 5.0.I want to use or bootstrap css to Primefaces custom components like List, table, selectOneListbox.
I am to apply css to normal component like button, link etc.

Comment: Your question is too general to be answered. As each component is a case in itself. There's no way to apply a general rule to all the components.

Comment: Why don't you just switch to PrimeFaces Bootstrap theme?

Answer (score 3):

It's possible, but due to reason that a internal structure of Primefaces's components are different from a plain HTML components with which Bootstrap supposed to work you will need to make hard job to accomplish that. You will need to debug every Primefaces component to see its internal structure and change Bootstrap's css file that it will correspond to internal classes of Primefaces's component.

Actually you have three alternatives (maybe more):

1. Like **BalusC** mentioned, Primefaces has its own implementation of Bootstrap theme: you can see it here: http://www.primefaces.org/themes IMHO, best option
2. Use Bootfaces JSF library: http://www.bootsfaces.net/ Pay attention that it's pretty new library and possible buggy. There isn't big community support like for Primefaces library.
3. Make you own Composite (or Custom) Components with desired structure and styling.